# wanting in on the action

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

Can you explain which meaning "on the action" has. The text is:

> She hugged us one more time, and Pippin and Frodo danced at our feet, wanting in **on the action**.

I can guess "wanting in on the action" is meaning "wanting a command", because Pippin and Frodo are dogs. Or I can guess "wanting in on the action" is meaning "wanting in an attention from their master". Or even I can guess "wanting in on the action" is meaning "wanting in the state free from any action" in analogy "put it on loudspeaker".

Can you correct me.

Comment: If you google "want in on the action meaning", you should find some answers that help.

Comment: _Please_ don't tell me Tolkien wrote 'wanting in on the action'.

Answer (score 1):

No, none of these are close.

"The action" is whatever is going on - in this case, presumably the hugging. Pippin and Frodo wanted to join in.